# How to read and print rows with common data in CSV using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science, rows

I am using below code to read the particular rows from csv using python and pandas.
But I am stuck while I want to print common data, text rows.
I want to print the row containing order code as  and 00157B. 
PFA Screenshot of scenario and attached code I am using.

```
rows = pd.read_csv('SampData.csv', skiprows=[1,3])
print(rows.head())
```

[image: Data Image]

Comment: It isn't real clear what you are trying to do.  You have a CSV with many order codes in it...  Are they unique by row?  or are there several line entries with the same order code that you would like to find?  It isn't clear what " < Test 1 > " is in your description.  Why are you using pandas?

Comment: Hey Jeff, I have huge data with 945 rows and multiple columns. I just wanted to search one name(text or term) like 00157B or <Test 1> and print those rows only. I want to search <Test 1> (This is the data format I have) then I should get all the rows to display with containing <Test 1>. It may have different comma separated values in it but I need entire row to print. Then I want to create another CSV of these common rows. This is the requirement.

Comment: OK.  You could use `pandas` for this, but it is probably more difficult than needed if all you want to do is locate rows in a csv and do something with them.  csv reader is pretty good at this.

Comment: Thanks ! But could you please tell me how to locate the row or rows with common data in it?

Answer (score 0):

Using Pandas for this could be done, but it is overkill.  I would just recommend the `csv` module, which is pretty easy to work with and has lots of online documentation.  Here is a toy example that does pretty much what you are looking for, I think

the data.csv file:

```
Order Number, Item, quantity
76XY, Cheese, 3
88TG, Broccoli, 44
76XY, Cookies, 1000
98UU, Coke, 1
```

A short file that manipulates 2 csv files:

```
import csv
input_file = 'data.csv'
output_file = 'found_orders.csv'
magic_order = '76XY'

with open(output_file, 'w') as target:
    target_writer = csv.writer(target)

    # open the source
    with open(input_file, 'r') as source:
        source_reader = csv.reader(source)
        # now both are "open and ready"
        # get the header from the first read of the source
        header = source_reader.__next__()

        # write to the modified file
        target_writer.writerow(header)

        # now use loop to loop through all rows and look for the order number
        # if found, print it to console and write it out to new csv
        # some extra print statements to see what is going on.  Recall
        # when csv reader reads a row, it reads it in as a list
        for row in source_reader:
            print('just read row: ', row)
            order = row[0]  # the position in the list of the order
            if order == magic_order:
                print('it matches the magic order')
                target_writer.writerow(row)
            else:
                print('not a match')
            print()

# if you use the 'with' command structure, it will close the files automatically
print('done')
```

Output (to console).  Output file is what you would expect to see.:

```
just read row:  ['76XY', ' Cheese', ' 3']
it matches the magic order

just read row:  ['88TG', ' Broccoli', ' 44']
not a match

just read row:  ['76XY', ' Cookies', ' 1000']
it matches the magic order

just read row:  ['98UU', ' Coke', ' 1']
not a match

done
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Comment: OK.  If it works for you, please accept the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of these -

In case you want to do a compare by the whole term in the `OrderCode` column ( for e.g. 00157B ) :

```
 filtered = rows[rows['OrderCode'] == '00157B'].reset_index(drop=True)
 filtered.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

In case you want to do a compare by a partial term in the `OrderCode` column ( for e.g. `OrderCodes` with `< Test 1 >` ):

```
filtered = rows[rows['OrderCode'].str.contains('< Test 1 >')].reset_index(drop=True)
filtered.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```